# Как вернуть, из файла конфигурации, string, с предшествующим @(at) символом?

Tags: c#, .net, config

Пусть есть файл конфигурации в котором

```
<tokenDefinitionConfig>
  <add TokenName="EngAbbreviation" TokenRegexPattern="\s*_([A-z]|[-])*\." />
  <add TokenName="RusAbbreviation" TokenRegexPattern="\s*_[А-я]*\." />
</tokenDefinitionConfig>
```

и стандартный класс описания для TokenDefinitionElement

```
    public class TokenDefinitionElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("tokenName", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
        public string TokenName
        {
            get
            {
                return this["tokenName"] as string;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("tokenRegexPattern", IsRequired = true)]
        public string TokenRegexPattern
        {
            get
            {
                return this["tokenRegexPattern"] as string;
            }
        }
    }
```

В самом файле config записать в значении TokenRegexPattern @(at) символ перед string не удается.

**Вопрос в том, как можно получить значение TokenRegexPattern  с предшествующим `@(at)` символом? 
Пример: `@"\s*_([A-z]|[-])*\."`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` перед строкой — это синтаксическая фича языка C#. Она отключает специальную интерпретацию `\` внутри строки.

Ваш файл, однако, в формате XML, в нём этой фичи нет. С другой стороны, в нём нет и интерпретации бэкслеша, так что как вы напишете, так и будет работать.

Интерпретация может быть дальше, в том месте, где ваша строка читается из XML и используется.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно записать в формате обычной строки без символа @:

```
<add TokenName="EngAbbreviation" TokenRegexPattern="\\s*_([A-z]|[-])*\\." />
```

То есть в данном случае заменить `\` на `\\`.